HTML table adds 4px around cells
I might be missing something stupid, but I need someone to assist.
I took an image and cut it into blocks using Photoshop. And I am trying to rebuild it using HTML Tables.
I managed to recreate the image in a Table in HTML successfully. I also managed to remove the spaces in-between the columns. But for some reason there is a 4px space between the rows that I don't know where it is coming from.
Here is my HTML code:
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:0px;border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td  style="height:100px"><img src="layer1.png" /></td>
                <td><img src="layer2.png" /></td>
                <td colspan="2"><img src="layer3.png" /></td>
                <td><img src="layer4.png" /></td>
                <td><img src="layer5.png" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="height:100px"><img src="layer6.png" /></td>
                <td rowspan="2"><img src="layer7.png" /></td>
                <td><img src="layer8.png" /></td>
                <td><img src="layer9.png" /></td>
                <td colspan="2"><img src="layer10.png"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><img src="layer11.png" /></td>
                <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"><img src="layer12.png" /></td>
                <td><img src="layer13.png" /></td>
                <td><img src="layer14.png" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><img src="layer15.png" /></td>
                <td><img src="layer16.png" /></td>
                <td><img src="layer17.png" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr><td colspan="3"><img src="layer18.png" /></td>
                <td><img src="layer19.png" /></td>
                <td><img src="layer20.png" /></td>
                <td><img src="layer21.png" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3"><img src="layer22.png" /></td>
                <td><img src="layer23.png" /></td>
                <td><img src="layer24.png" /></td>
                <td><img src="layer25.png" /></td>
                <td><img src="layer26.png" /></td>
                <td><img src="layer27.png" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><img src="layer28.png" /></td>
                <td><img src="layer29.png" /></td>
                <td><img src="layer30.png" /></td>
                <td><img src="layer31.png" /></td>
                <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"><img src="layer32.png" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

This is how it currently looks and I am not sure how to get the spaces in between away.
Screenshot of image pieced together using HTML tables
